# Can a ListView layout generation dynamic be displyed programatically

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

i have an activity in which i want to show a ListView like datagrid. the arraylist ITransducer[] is dynamic and i want to use the arraylist to generate the columns of listview.

## ListView

ITransducer1 | ITransducer2 | ITransducer3

## aa1          |   aa2        |  aa3

i had override getView() method, but i have to load a layout for listview like this
view = vi.inflate(R.layout.historical_data_details_item, null);

Can i generate listview layout dynamic by ITransducer[] ?

```
public class HistoricalDataDetailsActivity extends Activity {
ListView lvDetails;
Context context;
IDAL idal;
TransducerFactory tFactory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInBundleState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInBundleState);
    setContentView(R.layout.historical_data_details);
    context = this;
    tFactory = new TransducerFactory();
    lvDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDetails);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ITransducer[] its = new ITransducer[]{
        new AbsTransducer("aa1", TransducerType.AirPressure),
        new AbsTransducer("aa2", TransducerType.AirPressure),
        new AbsTransducer("aa3", TransducerType.Temperature)
    };
```

//        ListViewItemAdapter adapter = new ListViewItemAdapter(this, R.layout.historical_data_details_item,its);
//        lvDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

```
class ListViewItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ITransducer>{
    boolean HasHeader = false;

    public ListViewItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ITransducer[] objects){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.historical_data_details_item, null);

            TextView tvDate = new TextView(context);
            tvDate.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tvDate.setText("DateTime");

            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tLayout);
            layout.addView(tvDate);
            view = layout;

        }else
            view = convertView;

        return view;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you want to show aa1 | aa2 | aa3 like coloums?

Comment: yes,but the columns is dynamic by sqlite table

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       if (aa1!= null) {
            holder.aa1_tv.setText(aa1.getName());
        }
       if (aa2!= null) {
            holder.aa2_tv.setText(aa2.getName());
        }
       if (aa3!= null) {
            holder.aa3_tv.setText(aa3.getName());
        }
}
```

here `aa1/aa2/aa3` are object of a class representing column which you can initialize with your database.

Comment: hi Ankit,yes aa1,aa2,aa3 are objects of a class represent columns,but the amount of column of sqlite table is dynamic.it may be aa1/aa2/aa3/aa4/aa5 or aa1/aa2, i do not know how many objects of columns there are

Comment: ok, so basically it will scroll in horizontal direction, am i right? whats about number of rows?

Comment: hi Ankit, thank you so much for your response.i found the solution with       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730035/cursoradapter-slow-jerky-scroll